# How to get the number of clusters from a Kmeans Cluster Table in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to get the number of clusters that Biqquery automatically created with my code below

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL ch09eu.london_station_clusters
        OPTIONS(model_type='kmeans',
        standardize_features = true) AS
    
   SELECT * EXCEPT(station_name)
    from ch09eu.stationstats
```

Comment: If you find my answer helpful for your question, please consider to accept/upvote it as per [stackoverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/kmeans-tutorial#query_details_2) when the argument num_clusters is not explicitly passed while creating a model, BigQuery ML will choose a reasonable default based on the number of rows in the training data. Number of clusters can be found under the Details section in the model. Adding below a sample image for reference:

[image]